# Implementation of two-dimensional integer programming

Tags: mathematical-optimization, combinatorics, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a 2x2 integer matrix A and 2d integers vectors b, c. I want to maximize c∙x under the constrains x≥0 and Ax≤b when x ranges over 2d integer vectors. This is a [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) of two-dimensional integer linear program.

Is there an implementation of an efficient algorithm solving this problem with clear documentation/explanation?

It is easy to find some academic papers but I find it challenging to implement the pseudocode from those papers.

Comment: It may be easier to use a solver rather than writing your own.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Do you have some specific solver in mind?

Comment: This is a tiny MIP so any solver will do. Things may depend on from which environment you are calling it (C, Python, R etc), Google typically finds good suggestions.